# Placing an image/badge over the main image

Tags: android-studio, android-cardview, android-tv, leanback

I'm trying to place a mark or place a badge in my cardviews placing it in the middle of my card. The problem is, if I place the image with setMainimage both images show at the same time, the way I thought it would've worked was that first one shows, then followed by the second (which is smaller than the first), but that was not the case. The second way I tried was placing it with the styles but I'm using the same style for all my cards so the image is showing in all my cards. I would like some advice or some other way to do it.

Comment: It's hard to understand the arrangement you want to achieve. Could you mock it up perhaps and show a sketch? Are you trying to show an **overlay** over the main image?

Comment: indeed, i'm trying the LayoutInflater to achieve that  ,but i'm not sure if it will work .... i'll just need to put an image infront of  the main image of the cardview

Comment: You can see a Badge Overlay implementation that works on API 18+ (JELLY_BEAN_MR2) here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70624898/3079753

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple different ways you can achieve this. A simple way would be to just supply your own XML in the Presenter. In your XML, you can overlay your elements on top of each other however you'd like. Check [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5792496/is-there-any-way-to-have-ui-elements-slightly-overlap-one-on-top-of-one-another) for how to achieve it.

```
@Override
final protected BaseCardView onCreateView(Context context) {
    final BaseCardView cardView = new BaseCardView(context, null, R.style.YourCardStyle) {
        @Override
        public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
            // TODO: Add your functionality you want here! Showing/hiding elements.
            super.setSelected(selected);
        }
    };

    cardView.addView(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.card_your_custom_view, null));
    // Just some init method to set up your views visibility.
    initCardView(cardView);
    return cardView;
}
```

Then as long as you name your views correctly in the XML, everything should work as you want. You'll bind the model to your views in `onBindViewHolder`

```
public void onBindViewHolder(CardModel cardModel, BaseCardView cardView) {
    if (cardModel == null) {
        return;
    }
    Video video = cardModel.clip;
    Context context = cardView.getContext();

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) cardView.findViewById(R.id.main_image);
    TextView primaryText = (TextView) cardView.findViewById(R.id.primary_text);
    TextView secondaryText = (TextView) cardView.findViewById(R.id.secondary_text);
    TextView extraText = (TextView) cardView.findViewById(R.id.extra_text);
}
```

With the above code blocks, you'll have to replace `R.layout.card_your_custom_view` with your layout file which has `View`s with IDs `main_image`, `primary_text`, `secondary_text`, and 'extra_text`. As well as replacing`R.style.YourCardStyle` with your own card style. [Here](https://github.com/googlesamples/leanback-showcase/blob/master/app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml) are some examples of card styles you're allowed to use.

To get a better understanding of `Presenters`, check out [this folder](https://github.com/googlesamples/leanback-showcase/tree/master/app/src/main/java/android/support/v17/leanback/supportleanbackshowcase/cards/presenters) in the Leanback Showcase app.

Please let me know if this works.

Comment: it look's like you are using the type of cards that exist ..(underinfo,extra,etc)   making a new class with the basecard ,  not sure   if is that or in  my same card do what you just tell me ...

Comment: This code makes use of the BaseCardView they provide. If you don't care about any of the transitions then you could entirely build your own (and it's rather simple). This approach lets you utilize some of their classes functionality while supplying your own layout which allows for overlapping views and custom onSelection transitions.

Comment: soooo it's making a whole new kind of card ? i get that , the problem is that i already seen  that and for what i understand  you need to  make a whole new card extending the basecard  that you are going to use.....maybe i'm wrong ,i'm not sure ....

Comment: Correct, you'll be making a whole new kind of card which extends `BaseCardView` but you won't need a new class. You'll ONLY need a new layout (and optionally a style). You can re-use their card view and dynamically add your overlaying view, but that is subject to breaking if they change their CardView (so I don't suggest it). So I suggest making your own layout (card_your_custom_view). If you create a custom `Presenter` with the methods I specified above, everything should work.

Comment: ok ok ok i'll try it , i'm half way there ,already have my new layout ....

Comment: That's great! Try out my suggestion and let me know if you hit any issues.

Comment: ok i'm stuck hahahaha i have my style,my xml but now how do i show it ?

Comment: sorry i have never been so deep in the design sooo ,it's kind of hard ,i'm not sure how  to show the variables that i just make ... like i just said ,i got the style an the xml .... i just need to show it ,maybe it's a silly question but i'm having troubles with it ... ill post what i've got in a net line cause this thing has a limit

Comment: @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(Presenter.ViewHolder viewHolder, Object item) {
        MovieRent movieRent = (MovieRent) item;
        BaseCardView cardView = (BaseCardView) viewHolder.view;
        if (viewHolder == null) {
            return; }
        Context context = cardView.getContext();
        ImageView mainImage = (ImageView)            cardView.findViewById(R.id.main_image);
        ImageView icono = (ImageView)cardView.findViewById(R.id.icono);
        TextView nameMovie(TextView)cardView.findViewById(R.id.name_movie);
 }

Comment: Looks good, it feels like it's getting close! Okay so is this `onBind` method inside your custom presenter? If so, then all you need to do is pass your presenter to the `ArrayObjectAdapter` like [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/leanback-showcase/blob/master/app/src/main/java/android/support/v17/leanback/supportleanbackshowcase/app/page/PageAndListRowFragment.java#L184). Let me know if that works.

Comment: i found this widget in the view of the cards ... "android.support.v17.leanback.widget.NonOverlappingRelativeLayout" i'm not sure if would be a problem .....

Comment: ooooo this code is from the new sample from google isn't?

Comment: Yes, but the old code is very similar (as it relates to showing cards). The old sample app has a more simple implementation and the new showcase has a more complicated example. But once you understand how the Cards are being manipulated (through XML as well as presenters), then it makes it very easy to customize. You might even want to just open up their sample project but drop in your custom presenter (since it should work with a little tweaking).

Comment: @GilLarios Awesome! Since it sounds like this answer solved your problem, can you please click the check mark to accept my answer as the correct one? Thanks!

Comment: mmmm how can i do that?  i'm  new here hahaha :3

Comment: No problem! People on StackOverflow (SO) like getting the imaginary points which you get by upvoting people's posts (the up arrow) and by having your answers "accepted" (checkmark). You usually upvote questions/answers you think are pretty good. And clicking the checkmark marks this question as "resolved" so other people know a solution exists for the question you asked.